# How to solve [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, read-only, sdk, meizu-mx4

I'm new to this forum, and this is my first question:

I bought the meizu MX4 ubuntu edition today. I would like to install Ubuntu SDK. I tried to follow this walkthrough:

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/

Upon giving the following line in the terminal:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
```

I get the following:

```
[...]
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/etc/apt/sources.list.save'
touch: cannot touch '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-    
sdk-team_ubuntu_ppa.gpg': Read-only file system
```

I run ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-8.5) in developer mode. I'm kind of stuck now. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Unless your mount options in `/etc/fstab` are wrong, this usually means the kernel has detected FS corruption [or the hard disk had an I/O error] and the kernel marked the FS as read only to prevent further damage.  Check the system logs.  You may have to do a bit of recovery first.  Has nothing to do with the pkg you're trying to install.

Comment: Reviewers: This isn't off-topic as being about an end-of-life release; 15.04 was supported when this question was posted.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what to do.

I followed
[https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/ (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170427035437/https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)
and skipped the actual installation. There is a part **Enabling read-write mode** which fixed this problem. It says:

> #### Enabling read-write mode
>
> By default the system is read-only. You can switch to read-write mode,
> although this disables Ubuntu system upgrades. The main purpose for
> this is developing the Ubuntu system directly. This is not required
> for developing apps or using the system normally. Recovering from
> read-write mode is possible but requires reinstalling the system from
> scratch.
>
> **Warning**: Switching a device to read-write mode (and/or recovering from it) is an advanced feature and may result in complete data loss.
>
> **It also disables automatic over-the-air delta updates.** Accepting a full over-the-air update after making a device writable may undo
> changes you have made.
>
> ```
> $ phablet-config writable-image
> ```
>
> The system reboots in read-write mode.