# Try install TaxJar library but it would not be not install

Tags: python3, pip, odoo

I have try to install taxjar Library on my server. But when I try to install it is give me error.

> OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jsonobject'

my command is that :~ pip3 install -t /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages  taxjar

Comment: THe question is inclear, but most likely sudo is needed.

Comment: I will try with my odoo server and get the issue on there  and sudo is not working

Comment: Is it an Ubuntu server?

Comment: it is odoo.sh server hosted

Comment: Have you seen this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/712860/how-to-solve-errno-30-read-only-file-system